# Regular expression to match one or more characters every type?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

There are 3 types of characters: `A-Z`, `a-z` and `0-9`.

How to write regular expression to match words which have one or more characters in all three types?

For example:

Match: `abAcc88, Ua8za8, 88aA`

No match: `abc, 118, aa7, xxZZ, XYZ111`

This `boost::regex re("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$");` doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: So you want matches to have a combination of _all three_ of small letters, capital letters and digits?

Comment: can you just have a regex like - `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]` and have all combinations of `[a-z]`,`[A-Z]`, and `[0-9]` `or`ed? e.g.  `([a-z][A-Z][0-9])|([0-9][a-z][A-Z])`  You will have bunch of `|` for all combinations.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, no three but must have one or more small letters, one or more capital letters and one or more digits.

Comment: Sounds like password validation. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068843/password-validation-regex

Comment: @Joel Rondeau, yes, i want to get the passwords from large text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're testing each word separately:

```
boost::regex re("(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])");
```

No need for anchors.

---

Actually, in case boost doesn't support lookarounds:

```
boost::regex re(".*[a-z].*([A-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Z])|.*[A-Z].*([a-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[a-z])|.*[0-9].*([a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z])");
```

This is every combination, as @Bill has pointed out.

Comment: `or` ing all combinations will be ugly, so i was looking for some elegant solution....if possible :)

Comment: This works: boost::regex re("(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])\\S{8,}"); Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

At least IMO, trying to do this all with one regex is a poor idea. Though it's possible to make it work, you end up with an unreadable mess. The intent isn't apparent at all.

IMO, you'd be a lot better off expressing the logic more directly (though using a regex or two in the process won't hurt):

```
boost::regex lower("[a-z]");
boost::regex upper("[A-Z]");
boost::regex digit("[0-9]");

if (find(string, lower) && find(string,upper) && find(string,digit))
    // it passes
else
    // it fails
```

It takes little more than a glance for anybody with even the most minimal exposure to REs to figure out what this is doing (and even with no exposure to REs, it probably doesn't take really massive brilliance to figure out that `a-z` means "the characters from `a` to `z`").

Comment: And, despite potentially scanning the string three separate times, this probably performs better than a single large hairy regexp that tries to address all 6 possible orderings of the three character classes... I didn't benchmark, though...

Answer (score 1):

`(\w*[a-z]\w*[A-Z]\w*[0-9]\w*)|(\w*[a-z]\w*[0-9]\w*[A-Z]\w*)|(\w*[A-Z]\w*[a-z]\w*[0-9]\w*)|(\w*[A-Z]\w*[0-9]\w*[a-z]\w*)|(\w*[0-9]\w*[A-Z]\w*[a-z]\w*)|(\w*[0-9]\w*[a-z]\w*[A-Z]\w*)`

<kbd>l = lower</kbd><kbd>U = upper</kbd><kbd>N = number</kbd>

```
1. `(\w*[a-z]\w*[A-Z]\w*[0-9]\w*)` Match words __l__U___N___  
2. `(\w*[a-z]\w*[0-9]\w*[A-Z]\w*)` Match words __l__N___U___  
3. `(\w*[A-Z]\w*[a-z]\w*[0-9]\w*)` Match words __U__l___N___  
4. `(\w*[0-9]\w*[A-Z]\w*[a-z]\w*)` Match words __U__N___l___  
5. `(\w*[0-9]\w*[A-Z]\w*[a-z]\w*)` Match words __N__U___l___  
6. `(\w*[0-9]\w*[a-z]\w*[A-Z]\w*)` Match words __N__l___U___
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if we're gonna go the non-regex route, then why not take it all the way ;-)

```
const char* c = "abAcc88";
char b = 0b000;
for (; *c; c++) b |= 48 <= *c && *c <= 57  ? 0b001 :
                    (65 <= *c && *c <= 90  ? 0b010 :
                    (97 <= *c && *c <= 122 ? 0b100 :
                                             0b000 ));
if (b == 0b111)
{
    std::cout << "pass" << std::endl;
}
```

(It's not readable, etc.; I'm kidding.)