# Simple password regex, any potential issues?

Tags: regex, passwords

I have a quick question, I plan to use the following regex to test a password field:

```
/^\S{8,24}$/
```

The restrictions are:

Any character other than white-space is allowed, length between 8 and 24.

Does anyone anticipate any problems that might arise as a result of using this regex for a password?

Comment: Why can't I use whitespaces in a password? That is, why can't I use a passphrase such as '`The mammoth ran quickly`'?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why restrict whitespace?

Comment: And why restrict length?

Comment: Basically, user1593524, your regex _will_ suffice for your specified restrictions. That being said, I think the bigger issue is the restrictions themselves; those should probably be expanded. I understand that you don't want passwords to just be eight spaces! However, as it stands, a password of `aaaaaaaa` or `12345678` would be valid under the restrictions.

Comment: [XKCD - Password Strength](http://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: A good example of why offering the user some advice on the strength of an entered password is better than arbitrary restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you were asking whether the supplied restrictions are good:**

Not really, problems:

1. Some people want white-space.
2. Some people want a password longer than 24 characters.
3. Not forcing a certain range of characters allows people to enter very simple passwords which can very easily be cracked. For example, an 8-character password with only lowercase characters, as people will do, have 26<sup>8</sup> = 208827064576 possibilities, which could take as little as a few minutes to run through. Not to mention passwords with all character being the same. Many websites require at least:

   - A number
   - An uppercase character
   - A lowercase character

[Google "regex password validation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+password+validation) to get some ideas, there's a ton. [First link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068843/password-validation-regex).

**If you were asking whether the regex enforces the supplied restrictions:**

Yes, it's fine.

Comment: The latter, I was having a debate with a colleague who thought that the above regex would potentially fail to work if certain characters were pasted into the field.

Comment: Note: I have no intention of using this, I have a fairly robust regex for password checking that I have been using for years, it was just to settle a debate (a bit of a silly debate IMO).

Comment: Anything that classifies as white-space will cause it to fail. This could include characters which may not display as a visible space, but it's still there and still white-space. You should ask your fellow debatee for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Several:

- '11111111' is a valid password.
- Whitespace is not allowed.
- There is an upper bound (why not allow longer passwords?)

Using a regex for validating password strength is possible. One example:

```
^             # Start of string
(?=.*[a-z])   # Assert presence of at least one lowercase ASCII character
(?=.*[A-Z])   # Assert presence of at least one uppercase ASCII character
(?=.*[0-9])   # Assert presence of at least one ASCII digit
(?=.*\W)      # Assert presence of at least one non-alphanumeric character
(?!.*(.)\1\1) # Assert no triply repeated characters (aaa)
.{8,}         # Match at least 8 characters
$             # End of string
```