# Validation In java script

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Currently I'm attempting to create a regular expression to validate an user input field which requires the input to contain at least one of each of the following:

- an upper-case character
- a digit
- one of the following special characters: `& @ ! # +`

I attempted to create a regular expression that will validate the input correctly:

```
/^([a-zA-Z+]+[0-9+]+[&@!#+]+)$/i.test(userpass);
```

However, the input is not validated correctly.  How should I go about doing that?

Comment: Your regexp requires that all the letters come first, then all the numbers, then all the special characters. Also, you allow `+` in each of those groups, why?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - the list of special characters is in the OP's regex. Reading between the lines I think they want the test string to contain at least one of those "special" characters,  at least one letter, and at least one digit, in any order - but that regex enforces a specific order as per Barmar's comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Password validation regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068843/password-validation-regex)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/[a-z]/i.test(userpass) && /[0-9]/.test(userpass) && /[&@!#+]/.test(userpass)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simplify the regex with lookahead

```
 ^(?=.*[&@!#+])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$
  ------------- --------- -------
      |        |         |->match only if there's a digit ahead
      |        |->match only if there's a uppercase alphabet ahead
      |->match only if there's any 1 of [&@!#+]
```

`[A-Z]` would match a single uppercase letter

`\d` would match a single digit

---

OR use [search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp)

```
if(input.search(/\d/)!=-1 && input.search(/[&@!#+]/)!=-1) && input.search(/[A-Z]/)!=-1)
```